# Sending .ics event as email attachment in Laravel 4.1

Tags: php, email, laravel, calendar, attachment

I'm trying to send an .ics file as an email attachment using Laravel's `MAIL` class. When email is received, Gmail doesn't ask me to add event to calendar. However I can easily add the event to the calendar by uploading the received file. (Format is valid.) And there is a small calendar icon as well, yet there is no fancy formatting or any formatting at all.
Here's the code I'm using:

```
$filename = "invite.ics";

$data[0]  = "BEGIN:VCALENDAR";
$data[1] = "PRODID:-//Google Inc//Google Calendar 70.9054//EN";
$data[2] = "VERSION:2.0";
$data[3] = "CALSCALE:GREGORIAN";
$data[4] = "METHOD:REQUEST";
$data[8] = "BEGIN:VEVENT";
$data[9] = "DTSTART:20140312T080000Z";
$data[10] = "DTEND:20140312T103000Z";
$data[11] = "DTSTAMP:20140312T072230Z";
$data[12] = "UID:aj5nufn03q772ukb54u1pp6c88@example.com";
$data[13] = "CREATED:20140312T072126Z";
$data[14] = "DESCRIPTION:Hair cut\, 2\,5h\, 300Eur";
$data[15] = "LAST-MODIFIED:20140312T072206Z";
$data[16] = "LOCATION:";
$data[17] = "SEQUENCE:0";
$data[18] = "STATUS:CONFIRMED";
$data[19] = "SUMMARY:Matu griešana";
$data[20] = "TRANSP:OPAQUE";
$data[21] = "END:VEVENT";
$data[22] = "END:VCALENDAR";


$data = implode("\r\n", $data);
header("text/calendar");
file_put_contents($filename, "\xEF\xBB\xBF".  $data);

Mail::send('emails.temp', array(), function($message) use($filename)
{
    $message->from('jon@example', 'Jon Doe');
    $message->to('osvalds.neiders@gmail.com')->subject('Registration information');

    $message->attach($filename, array('mime' => "text/calendar"));
});
```

Comment: So as it turns out, the problem is now how to set mime type of email's body to `text/calendar`.

Comment: Did you get it to work in the end?

Answer (score -1):

create a file on a destination and attache it

```
name ="invite.ics"
matter= 
"BEGIN:VCALENDAR
PRODID:-//Microsoft Corporation//Outlook 11.0 MIMEDIR//EN
VERSION:2.0
METHOD:PUBLISH
BEGIN:VEVENT
ORGANIZER:MAILTO:aaaa@aaaa.com
DTSTART:20150315T170000Z
DTEND:20150315T180000Z
LOCATION:La Taska
TRANSP:OPAQUE
SEQUENCE:0
UID:d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e
DTSTAMP:20150313T150000Z
DESCRIPTION:The Programn Description
SUMMARY:The Programn Description
PRIORITY:5
CLASS:PUBLIC
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR"
```

Comment: Uh... I don't think this solves the problem.  The OP is having trouble attaching such an event.  You're suggesting that the answer to the question is the question itself.